# Dynamic Route In React Displaying Blank Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement dynamic routing in my app so that I could view products of a store separately. Basically I'm building an app where user can add stores and view their items, so I created a dynamic route for the items component so that I could access each store's id in the params and render the items of that store. I made the route and entered some random numbers in the params and I was getting those value in the component but the html part of it was not rendering just showing a blank page,

This is the place where I setup the route:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import StoresPreview from "../../components/StoresPreview/StoresPreview";
import ItemsMap from "../../components/Items/ItemsMap";
const StoresPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<StoresPreview />} />
        <Route path=":number" element={<ItemsMap />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default StoresPage;
```

This is the items map component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ItemsMap = () => {
  const { number } = useParams();
  console.log(number);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{`the id is ${number}`}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemsMap;
```

This is app component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/NavbarWithDrawer/NavBar";
import HomePage from "./components/Home/Home";
import AdminSignIn from "./components/AdminSignIn/AdminSignIn";
import StoresPage from "./pages/StoresPage/StoresPage";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />}>
          <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="stores/*" element={<StoresPage />} />
          <Route path="signin" element={<AdminSignIn />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried adding an outlet to storesPreview hoping it would render the itemsMap html but didn't work.

Comment: The code appears fine to me and I'm unable to [reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-route-in-react-displaying-blank-page-w7csc4) any issue accessing and rendering the `ItemsMap` component on `"/stores/:number"`. The ***only*** place I suspect there may be an issue is in the `Navbar` component if it isn't rendering an `Outlet` for its nested routes to be rendered into. Are you able to access and render the `StoresPreview` component on `"/stores"`?

Comment: @DrewReese yes the StoresPreview is working fine and being rendered and i also added an outlet at the end

Comment: `StoresPreview` doesn't need an `Outlet` since it's not rendering any nested routes. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live? Feel free to fork the one I linked and edit it to include more of your actual code.

Comment: @DrewReese sorry it took me a while, since this is a mern stack project ive created two sandboxes one for the actual frontend react and the express backend

react: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/zayfaali/point-of-sale-react/draft/festive-wave?file=/src/context/stores.context.js:5,42&workspaceId=b52695eb-a12e-4fc3-8bff-dbd77faff029

and the  backend : https://codesandbox.io/p/github/zayfaali/point-of-sale-api/main

i hope that u can find the problem

the login details are: admin@gmail.com and password : admin

Comment: The frontend sandbox doesn't load. Looks like you shared a link to a draft.

Comment: thats my bad im really new to so here u go codesandbox.io/p/github/zayfaali/point-of-sale-react/main u might have to change the host to the api in the context to get it fully work as it was in my pc, please take a loot at this i really need help understanding @DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually working, the page isn't blank. The issue is that the "this is the itemsMap" of the `ItemsMap` component is rendered underneath the app header bar `Navbar`.

[image]

Adding a `padding-top: 64px;` (*the height of the app bar component*) CSS rule to the container div element should push the content down into view.

Example:

```
const ItemsMap = () => {
  const { number } = useParams();

  return (
    <div style={{ paddingTop: "64px"}}>
      <h1>The id is {number}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

This only addresses/fixes the issue for this one `ItemsMap` component though. A better solution is to apply this padding in the parent layout route component rendering the `Outlet`.

Example:

```
export default function Navbar() {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
          ...
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer ... >
          ...
        </Drawer>
      </Box>
      <div style={{ paddingTop: "64px"}}> {/* Apply padding here */}
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```